# Most efficient way to split ng-repeat in two separated div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code (working) but in my mind it's not the most efficient way to do the separation between the 'answer'=1 and the other.

```html
<div id="important-question">
---> Important questions 

 <div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:{answer:1}" >

  <br/><br/><label> {{q.name}} </label><br/><br/>
 
</div>
</div>

<div id="useless-question">

---> Useless questions

 <div ng-repeat="q in questions | filter:{answer:0}" >

  <br/><br/><label> {{q.name}} </label><br/><br/>
    
</div>

</div>
```

If you see a better way, please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [groupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) filter:

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.questions=[
      {name:'11',answer:1},
      {name:'12',answer:1},
      {name:'01',answer:0},
      {name:'02',answer:0},
      {name:'3',answer:3},
    ]
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.16/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-attr-id="{{(key == 1 ? 'important' : 'useless') + '-questions'}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in questions | groupBy: 'answer'" ng-if='key==1||key==0'>
      {{key == 1 ? 'Important' : 'Useless'}} questions
      <div ng-repeat="q in value" >
          <br/><br/><label> {{q.name}} </label><br/><br/> 
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i wanted to do  !